# ElectronJs: Cannot find module 'electron-cookies'

Tags: node.js, cookies, npm, electron

Here is my project structure

```
helloWorld
-app
--package.json
--app.js
--node_modules
--public
---index.html
---package.json
---node_modules
-dist
-build
-package.json
```

I am running the index.html on localhost made using nodejs in electron.

I want to use persistent cookies in Electron app. In order to do this, I am using `electron-cookies` but I am getting `Cannot find module 'electron-cookies'`

I have installed `electron-cookies` in `app>>package.json` and `app>>public>>package.json` as well but nothing seems to be working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <script>
        require('electron-cookies')
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.1/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularJS Cookies Example</title>
</head>
```

End of the day my task is to create cookies, please suggest if there is any alternative that can create persistent cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native Electron Cookies interface. The electron-cookies third party lib you're trying to load seems a little out of date and is probably no longer working with current versions of Electron.